# Javascript - finally executes before try block finishes with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS application. I have a form. On submit I'm calling a function. I have used the javascript **try/catch/finally block**

```
$scope.save = function() {
          try {
                //Block of code to try
              $scope.submit.text = "Submitting";
              $scope.submit.disable = true;
              $timeout(function(){
                  alert('successfully saved');
              }, 5000);
            }
            catch(err) {
                //Block of code to handle errors
            } 
            finally {
                alert("finally");
                $scope.submit.text = "Submit";
                $scope.submit.disable = false;
            }

      }
```

I used a timer for now. But later I may use AJAX call. the problem is

finally block gets executed before the time finishes. How to solve this?

Comment: You need to move your try catch finally block within the timeout function as timeout function is async.

Comment: check this out: http://know.cujojs.com/tutorials/async/mastering-async-error-handling-with-promises

Comment: You can also convert any async function call into a `kriskowal q`-like promise object, which is extensively used in AngularJS, called `$q`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason why the finally method gets executed before the time is finished is that javascript methods are not running asynchronous. `Promises` will solve this problem.

Here is how promise is defined in [`q.js`](https://github.com/kriskowal/q) which is used in angular:

> A promise is an object that represents the return value or the thrown
>   exception that the function may eventually provide. A promise can also
>   be used as a proxy for a remote object to overcome latency.

One of the guarantees promises make is that the either the success or the error callback will be invoked, but never both. What happens if you need to ensure a specific function executes regardless of the result of the promise? You can do this by registering that function on the promise using the `finally()` method.

Suppose you have a function `getData()` where you are making some $http request and obtain some data from backend. Then you can use:

```
var promise = getData()
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data)
    }, function(error) {
      console.error(error)
    })
    .finally(function() {
      console.log()
    })
})
```